# What does 'arg1 must be a string, bytes or code object' mean? exec()

Tags: python

[an image of the error message for anyone interested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vnXm.png)

trying to make a simple version of a language translator to a language I made that is similar to one from Outer wilds. but when I try to execute one of the letters for turtle to draw it says as the image above or

arg1 must be a string, bytes or code object

As I am not an amazing coder, I have no clue what that means.

[This is the code that I have written and I want to exec()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1MVt.png)

There is another image containing the code I want to exec()

if anyone can tell me how to solve this thanks! and if you are able to use more simple python and dumb the answer down an little bit so I can understand then that would also be massively helpful!

if you can't dumb it down for me, no problem!

Comment: Please include the necessary artifacts directly in the question. There is an option to link an image to the posting in the posting form and you can write the code  and enclose with starting and ending triple back-ticks '`' to achieve code highlighting, or click the form button that says 'code'.

Comment: You're not showing us anything that calls exec(), so it's really hard to know what's going on.

Comment: i simply put:

exec(h)
exec(i)
but on different lines

Comment: The error is telling you are passing the wrong type of object to the `exec` function, and it's telling you the types of objects it accepts (string objects, bytes objects, and code objects)

Comment: `exec()` is usually called with a plain string of Python code, for example `exec("x = 5")`.  The variable `h`, whatever it is, is not a plain string.

Comment: You must provide a [mcve]. Please do not post images of code or links to code. Post code as formatted text in the question itself

Comment: is there a way I can do this then? my plan is that the user can input a word or sentence and then the turtle will draw it using the letters so executing in some way is (from my knowledge) the best way to do that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't think I understand the question. Do you know what `arg 1` refers to in this context? Do you know what a string is? What a `bytes` is? What a `code object` is? I assume you understand what "must be" means. What exactly is the point of confusion?

Comment: Please read [ask], and [do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Try to explain the *actual problem* starting from the beginning - *what should happen* when you run the code? Why do you want to use `exec` to solve the problem? What, to your understanding, is the *purpose* of `exec`?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = T.fd(20)
b = T.fd(20); T.rt(60); T.fd(20)
```

Neither of those statements does what you think they do.  The first statement calls the `fd` function immediately (presumably moving the turtle forward by 20), and returns None, so `None` will be stored in `a`.

The second line also does a forward 20 and stores that return value in `b`.  It then does a right 60 and a forward 20, but nothing about those will be stored in `b`.  Those are completely separate statements.

The bottom line is, if you want to store up a macro to be executed later with `exec`, then those lines MUST BE STRINGS.  You don't have any strings.  So, change your code to:

```
a = "T.fd(20)"
b = "T.fd(20); T.rt(60); T.fd(20)"
...etc...
```

Then it will do what you want.  This is not the BEST way to do this, because `exec` is a bad habit, but it will do what you want.  The better way would be to do something like:

```
a = "F20"
b = "F20,R60,F20"
```

and then write a little interpreter to convert those to turtle movements.

Comment: Ah! Yes thank you Tim! it worked. There are probably better ways yes, but I am not greeat at python yet and still learning so it is the best way I know of at the moment! thanks though!

Comment: "There are probably better ways" it seems like what you intend to do is to make and call *functions*. Like, you know how you get to write `t.fd(20)` and it just makes the turtle move forward - you *don't have to* figure out the code to, for example, decide which pixels on the screen have to turn what colour? That's because `t.fd` wraps up the work for you. It turns out that *you can make your own wrapping-ups of code*, and in fact this is one of the most fundamental ideas in programming.

Comment: But if you are asking questions like this, it is probably better that you try to *follow a Python tutorial from start to finish, and not try to invent your own projects until the end*.

Comment: A few people have said it gently, but I will say it in bold: **you should not be using `exec()` for this**.  I promise you that it is making your life difficult and hindering your learning.  Learn how to use `def` and you will be amazed at how much easier your life gets.

Comment: how would I go about running the defenition? I have only used them once or twice before and cant remember how they are used